# build a set of values in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I've been scratching my head over this problem for a couple of days and i feel my vision a bit tunneled right now, so i thought maybe you can shed some light on this matter :)

so this app runs some code, gets some values till it gets to this part:

```
for y in query2:
        del list2[:]
        list2.append(y.share_with)
        data[x]=print(list2)
```

data is a dictionary, and the keys 'x' are being added correctly to the dictionary but as you have guessed the problem is with list2.
i want to add a set of values (returned from query2) to each 'x' key, 
i thought to initialize the list2 outside the loop empty it on each iteration and store it in the dictionary but that doesn't work obviously.

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

**EDIT**:

That's the code that works:

```
for x in output:
query2 = oc_share.select(oc_share.share_with).where(oc_share.file_target == x)
list2 = []
      for y in query2:

           list2.append(y.share_with)
           data[x]=print(list2)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You're adding the same list object each time. Replace `del list2[:]` with `list2 = []`, so you get a new list for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, you gave me the solution :) to clarify : if i replace it, it only gives me one value. but if i initiate the list before the iteration..bingo ! :) but that's my fault for not posting the previous line. ill update my question

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

That's the code that works:

for x in output:
query2 = oc_share.select(oc_share.share_with).where(oc_share.file_target == x)
list2 = []
      for y in query2:

```
       list2.append(y.share_with)
       data[x]=print(list2)
```